# SolrNet delete may be broken because of PostSolrConnection

Tags: post, solrnet

I'm using Solrnet 0.4. I lifted the following decorator which implements the PostSolrConnection to send queries over post:

```
 public SolrSearchRepository(int caseID, string solrServer)           
{           
    this.facility = new SolrNetFacility(solrServer);
    this.facility.AddCore(caseID.ToString(), typeof(SolrDocument), string.Format("{0}/{1}", solrServer, caseID));
    this.container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(Component.For<ISolrConnection>()
             .ImplementedBy<PostSolrConnection>()
             .DependsOn(Parameter.ForKey("serverUrl").Eq(solrServer)));
    this.container.AddFacility(this.facility);
    solrOperation = container.Resolve<ISolrOperations<SolrDocument>>(caseID.ToString());                    
}
```

We index documents with mutliple pages, where each page has a unique id. When a document needs to be deleted instead of deleting each page, we use the "docid" field in a query to delete all instances of that document (its docid is uinque). We implement the delete as follows:

```
public void Delete(string fileIds)
{
    string[] docIds = fileIds.Split(new char[1] { ',' });
    AbstractSolrQuery deleteQuery = new SolrQuery(string.Format("docid:{0}", docIds[0]));
    AbstractSolrQuery appendDeleteQuery = null;
    for (int i = 1; i < docIds.Length; i++)
    {
        appendDeleteQuery = new SolrQuery(string.Format("docid:{0}", docIds[i]));
        deleteQuery = deleteQuery || appendDeleteQuery;
    }

    solrOperation.Delete(deleteQuery);
    solrOperation.Commit();
```

}

Looking at my Tomcat 7.0 logs, when I execute the Delete the output is the following:

> INFO: {deleteByQuery=(docid:2341 OR docid:2350)} 0 0
>   Mar 25, 2014 12:09:24 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
>   INFO: [11119] webapp=/solr path=/update params={version=2.2} status=0 QTime=0 
>   Mar 25, 2014 12:09:24 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 commit
>   INFO: start commit(optimize=false,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false,softCommit=false)
>   Mar 25, 2014 12:09:24 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrDeletionPolicy onCommit
>   INFO: SolrDeletionPolicy.onCommit: commits:num=2
>       commit{dir=F:\SOLR11119\index.20140325120820,segFN=segments_qa,version=1326842297456,generation=946,filenames=[_b4.fnm, _vh_0.tim, _vh_0.tip, _ww.nrm, _qu_0.tip, _xa.fnm, _qu.fdt, _qu.fdx, _qu.fnm, _eb.nrm, _x9.fdt, _xa.fdx, _x9.fdx, _xa.fdt, _xe_0.tim, _xe_0.tip, _qu_0.tim, _wb_0.frq, _xf_0.tim, _x9.fnm, _xf_0.tip, _x9.per, _xe_0.prx, _qu.per, _xc.per, _eb_0.prx, _w1_0.tip, _w1_0.tim, _lj_1b.del, _xe_0.frq, _x9_0.tip, _lj_0.frq, _wb.fnm, _b4.fdx, _x9_0.tim, _xe.nrm, _b4.fdt, _b4.nrm, _xb.fdt, _xc.fnm, _xb.fdx, _xb.nrm, _xa.nrm, _xe.per, _w1.per, _eb_0.frq, _xa_0.frq, _w1_0.prx, _vh.per, segments_qa, _ww.per, _x9_3.del, _wb.nrm, _xf.nrm, _ww_0.prx, _x9_0.prx, _xf.per, _xc_0.tip, _eb.fdx, _eb.fdt, _xc.fdt, _xb.fnm, _vh_0.prx, _xc_0.tim, _vh_0.frq, _xa_0.prx, _lj.per, _xc.fdx, _xc_0.prx, _lj.fdt, _lj.fdx, _eb_0.tip, _qu_c.del, _x9.nrm, _w1.fdx, _xa_0.tip, _eb_0.tim, _lj_0.prx, _xa_0.tim, _xf.fnm, _w1.fdt, _xa.per, _b4.per, _eb.fnm, _xb_0.frq, _vh_13.del, _xb_0.tip, _xe.fnm, _xb_0.tim, _ww_0.tip, _eb.per, _ww_0.tim, _vh.fdt, _ww.fnm, _qu_0.prx, _xb_0.prx, _wb_0.prx, _vh.fdx, _xc_0.frq, _w1_0.frq, _b4_0.frq, _b4_0.prx, _xf_0.prx, _vh.nrm, _w1.fnm, _xf_0.frq, _ww_0.frq, _eb_2.del, _qu_0.frq, _ww.fdt, _wb_0.tim, _xe.fdt, _wb.per, _qu.nrm, _lj.fnm, _xe.fdx, _b4_0.tip, _b4_0.tim, _ww.fdx, _x9_0.frq, _wb_0.tip, _lj_0.tip, _xf.fdx, _xc.nrm, _vh.fnm, _lj_0.tim, _w1.nrm, _wb.fdt, _xb.per, _xf.fdt, _lj.nrm, _wb.fdx]
>       commit{dir=F:\SOLR11119\index.20140325120820,segFN=segments_qb,version=1326842297457,generation=947,filenames=[_b4.fnm, _vh_0.tim, _vh_0.tip, _ww.nrm, _qu_0.tip, _lj_1c.del, _xa.fnm, _qu.fdt, _qu.fdx, _qu.fnm, _eb.nrm, _x9.fdt, _xa.fdx, _x9.fdx, _xa.fdt, _xe_0.tim, _xe_0.tip, _qu_0.tim, _wb_0.frq, _xf_0.tim, _x9.fnm, _xf_0.tip, _x9.per, _xe_0.prx, _qu.per, _xc.per, _eb_0.prx, _w1_0.tip, _w1_0.tim, _xe_0.frq, _x9_0.tip, _lj_0.frq, _wb.fnm, _b4.fdx, _x9_0.tim, _xe.nrm, _b4.fdt, _b4.nrm, _xb.fdt, _xc.fnm, _xb.fdx, _xb.nrm, _xa.nrm, _xe.per, _w1.per, _eb_0.frq, _xa_0.frq, _w1_0.prx, _vh.per, _ww.per, _x9_3.del, _wb.nrm, _xf.nrm, _ww_0.prx, _x9_0.prx, _xf.per, _xc_0.tip, _eb.fdx, segments_qb, _eb.fdt, _xc.fdt, _xb.fnm, _vh_0.prx, _xc_0.tim, _vh_0.frq, _xa_0.prx, _lj.per, _xc.fdx, _xc_0.prx, _lj.fdt, _lj.fdx, _eb_0.tip, _qu_c.del, _x9.nrm, _w1.fdx, _xa_0.tip, _eb_0.tim, _lj_0.prx, _xa_0.tim, _xf.fnm, _w1.fdt, _xa.per, _b4.per, _eb.fnm, _xb_0.frq, _vh_13.del, _xb_0.tip, _xe.fnm, _xb_0.tim, _ww_0.tip, _eb.per, _ww_0.tim, _vh.fdt, _ww.fnm, _qu_0.prx, _xb_0.prx, _wb_0.prx, _vh.fdx, _xc_0.frq, _w1_0.frq, _b4_0.frq, _b4_0.prx, _xf_0.prx, _vh.nrm, _w1.fnm, _xf_0.frq, _ww_0.frq, _eb_2.del, _qu_0.frq, _ww.fdt, _wb_0.tim, _xe.fdt, _wb.per, _qu.nrm, _lj.fnm, _xe.fdx, _b4_0.tip, _b4_0.tim, _ww.fdx, _x9_0.frq, _wb_0.tip, _lj_0.tip, _xf.fdx, _xc.nrm, _vh.fnm, _lj_0.tim, _w1.nrm, _wb.fdt, _xb.per, _xf.fdt, _lj.nrm, _wb.fdx]
>   Mar 25, 2014 12:09:24 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrDeletionPolicy updateCommits
>   INFO: newest commit = 1326842297457
>   Mar 25, 2014 12:09:24 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher 
>   INFO: Opening Searcher@ebe0a7 main
>   Mar 25, 2014 12:09:24 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 commit
>   INFO: end_commit_flush
>   Mar 25, 2014 12:09:24 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
>   INFO: autowarming Searcher@ebe0a7 main{DirectoryReader(segments_qb:1326842297457 _b4(4.0):C11004 _lj(4.0):C10822/393 _eb(4.0):C5135/191 _qu(4.0):C6594/272 _vh(4.0):C2403/712 _ww(4.0):C474 _wb(4.0):C201 _w1(4.0):C231 _x9(4.0):C303/3 _xa(4.0):C1 _xb(4.0):C1 _xc(4.0):C1 _xe(4.0):C1 _xf(4.0):C10)} from Searcher@cf004e main{DirectoryReader(segments_qa:1326842297456 _b4(4.0):C11004 _lj(4.0):C10822/363 _eb(4.0):C5135/191 _qu(4.0):C6594/272 _vh(4.0):C2403/712 _ww(4.0):C474 _wb(4.0):C201 _w1(4.0):C231 _x9(4.0):C303/3 _xa(4.0):C1 _xb(4.0):C1 _xc(4.0):C1 _xe(4.0):C1 _xf(4.0):C10)}
>       fieldValueCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
>   Mar 25, 2014 12:09:24 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
>   INFO: autowarming result for Searcher@ebe0a7 main{DirectoryReader(segments_qb:1326842297457 _b4(4.0):C11004 _lj(4.0):C10822/393 _eb(4.0):C5135/191 _qu(4.0):C6594/272 _vh(4.0):C2403/712 _ww(4.0):C474 _wb(4.0):C201 _w1(4.0):C231 _x9(4.0):C303/3 _xa(4.0):C1 _xb(4.0):C1 _xc(4.0):C1 _xe(4.0):C1 _xf(4.0):C10)}
>       fieldValueCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
>   Mar 25, 2014 12:09:24 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
>   INFO: autowarming Searcher@ebe0a7 main{DirectoryReader(segments_qb:1326842297457 _b4(4.0):C11004 _lj(4.0):C10822/393 _eb(4.0):C5135/191 _qu(4.0):C6594/272 _vh(4.0):C2403/712 _ww(4.0):C474 _wb(4.0):C201 _w1(4.0):C231 _x9(4.0):C303/3 _xa(4.0):C1 _xb(4.0):C1 _xc(4.0):C1 _xe(4.0):C1 _xf(4.0):C10)} from Searcher@cf004e main{DirectoryReader(segments_qa:1326842297456 _b4(4.0):C11004 _lj(4.0):C10822/363 _eb(4.0):C5135/191 _qu(4.0):C6594/272 _vh(4.0):C2403/712 _ww(4.0):C474 _wb(4.0):C201 _w1(4.0):C231 _x9(4.0):C303/3 _xa(4.0):C1 _xb(4.0):C1 _xc(4.0):C1 _xe(4.0):C1 _xf(4.0):C10)}
>       filterCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
>   Mar 25, 2014 12:09:24 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
>   INFO: autowarming result for Searcher@ebe0a7 main{DirectoryReader(segments_qb:1326842297457 _b4(4.0):C11004 _lj(4.0):C10822/393 _eb(4.0):C5135/191 _qu(4.0):C6594/272 _vh(4.0):C2403/712 _ww(4.0):C474 _wb(4.0):C201 _w1(4.0):C231 _x9(4.0):C303/3 _xa(4.0):C1 _xb(4.0):C1 _xc(4.0):C1 _xe(4.0):C1 _xf(4.0):C10)}
>       filterCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
>   Mar 25, 2014 12:09:24 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
>   INFO: autowarming Searcher@ebe0a7 main{DirectoryReader(segments_qb:1326842297457 _b4(4.0):C11004 _lj(4.0):C10822/393 _eb(4.0):C5135/191 _qu(4.0):C6594/272 _vh(4.0):C2403/712 _ww(4.0):C474 _wb(4.0):C201 _w1(4.0):C231 _x9(4.0):C303/3 _xa(4.0):C1 _xb(4.0):C1 _xc(4.0):C1 _xe(4.0):C1 _xf(4.0):C10)} from Searcher@cf004e main{DirectoryReader(segments_qa:1326842297456 _b4(4.0):C11004 _lj(4.0):C10822/363 _eb(4.0):C5135/191 _qu(4.0):C6594/272 _vh(4.0):C2403/712 _ww(4.0):C474 _wb(4.0):C201 _w1(4.0):C231 _x9(4.0):C303/3 _xa(4.0):C1 _xb(4.0):C1 _xc(4.0):C1 _xe(4.0):C1 _xf(4.0):C10)}
>       queryResultCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=16,cumulative_hits=3,cumulative_hitratio=0.18,cumulative_inserts=13,cumulative_evictions=0}
>   Mar 25, 2014 12:09:24 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
>   INFO: autowarming result for Searcher@ebe0a7 main{DirectoryReader(segments_qb:1326842297457 _b4(4.0):C11004 _lj(4.0):C10822/393 _eb(4.0):C5135/191 _qu(4.0):C6594/272 _vh(4.0):C2403/712 _ww(4.0):C474 _wb(4.0):C201 _w1(4.0):C231 _x9(4.0):C303/3 _xa(4.0):C1 _xb(4.0):C1 _xc(4.0):C1 _xe(4.0):C1 _xf(4.0):C10)}
>       queryResultCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=16,cumulative_hits=3,cumulative_hitratio=0.18,cumulative_inserts=13,cumulative_evictions=0}
>   Mar 25, 2014 12:09:24 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
>   INFO: autowarming Searcher@ebe0a7 main{DirectoryReader(segments_qb:1326842297457 _b4(4.0):C11004 _lj(4.0):C10822/393 _eb(4.0):C5135/191 _qu(4.0):C6594/272 _vh(4.0):C2403/712 _ww(4.0):C474 _wb(4.0):C201 _w1(4.0):C231 _x9(4.0):C303/3 _xa(4.0):C1 _xb(4.0):C1 _xc(4.0):C1 _xe(4.0):C1 _xf(4.0):C10)} from Searcher@cf004e main{DirectoryReader(segments_qa:1326842297456 _b4(4.0):C11004 _lj(4.0):C10822/363 _eb(4.0):C5135/191 _qu(4.0):C6594/272 _vh(4.0):C2403/712 _ww(4.0):C474 _wb(4.0):C201 _w1(4.0):C231 _x9(4.0):C303/3 _xa(4.0):C1 _xb(4.0):C1 _xc(4.0):C1 _xe(4.0):C1 _xf(4.0):C10)}
>       documentCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=1565,cumulative_hits=15,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=1550,cumulative_evictions=1010}
>   Mar 25, 2014 12:09:24 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
>   INFO: autowarming result for Searcher@ebe0a7 main{DirectoryReader(segments_qb:1326842297457 _b4(4.0):C11004 _lj(4.0):C10822/393 _eb(4.0):C5135/191 _qu(4.0):C6594/272 _vh(4.0):C2403/712 _ww(4.0):C474 _wb(4.0):C201 _w1(4.0):C231 _x9(4.0):C303/3 _xa(4.0):C1 _xb(4.0):C1 _xc(4.0):C1 _xe(4.0):C1 _xf(4.0):C10)}
>       documentCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=1565,cumulative_hits=15,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=1550,cumulative_evictions=1010}
>   Mar 25, 2014 12:09:24 PM org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener newSearcher
>   INFO: QuerySenderListener sending requests to Searcher@ebe0a7 main{DirectoryReader(segments_qb:1326842297457 _b4(4.0):C11004 _lj(4.0):C10822/393 _eb(4.0):C5135/191 _qu(4.0):C6594/272 _vh(4.0):C2403/712 _ww(4.0):C474 _wb(4.0):C201 _w1(4.0):C231 _x9(4.0):C303/3 _xa(4.0):C1 _xb(4.0):C1 _xc(4.0):C1 _xe(4.0):C1 _xf(4.0):C10)}
>   Mar 25, 2014 12:09:24 PM org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener newSearcher
>   INFO: QuerySenderListener done.
>   Mar 25, 2014 12:09:24 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore registerSearcher
>   INFO: [11119] Registered new searcher Searcher@ebe0a7 main{DirectoryReader(segments_qb:1326842297457 _b4(4.0):C11004 _lj(4.0):C10822/393 _eb(4.0):C5135/191 _qu(4.0):C6594/272 _vh(4.0):C2403/712 _ww(4.0):C474 _wb(4.0):C201 _w1(4.0):C231 _x9(4.0):C303/3 _xa(4.0):C1 _xb(4.0):C1 _xc(4.0):C1 _xe(4.0):C1 _xf(4.0):C10)}
>   Mar 25, 2014 12:09:24 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher close
>   INFO: Closing Searcher@cf004e main
>       fieldValueCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
>       filterCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
>       queryResultCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=16,cumulative_hits=3,cumulative_hitratio=0.18,cumulative_inserts=13,cumulative_evictions=0}
>       documentCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=1565,cumulative_hits=15,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=1550,cumulative_evictions=1010}
>   Mar 25, 2014 12:09:24 PM org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor finish

---

I don't see the xml query (like update?stream.body=docid:2827&commit=true) anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: The log does say: `INFO: {deleteByQuery=(docid:2341 OR docid:2350)}`

Comment: Thanks for looking into it Mauricio. It would've been difficult to answer the question because the culprit was masked by a variable. The `solrServer` variable was set to the slave, so of course, I would delete, and within seconds (20 seconds, per my slave config) the record would pop back up. So, after noticing this, I routed my queries to the master. And, whala, problem solved!